# Query running in sql but not running from .Net

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am trying to write sql query in c# .net code that returns a single record. It runs correctly when i executed in sql with the provided parameters but returns no rows when executed from .Net code. Not sure what the problem is ? Below code explains the flow of control

.Net code

```
 public class FedExciseExpense
{
    public float DomicileId { get; set; }
    public float CoveragePolicyTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool Is953D { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}


public List<FedExciseExpense> GetFedExciseTaxExpenses(int industryId, int domicileId,int coveragePolicyTypeId, bool is953D)
        {
            var sql = @"select distinct gm.geographyBaseId as DomicileId, fedt.is953d as Is953D, fedt.coveragePolicyTypeId as CoveragePolicyTypeId, fedt.value as Value
                                from fedExciseTax fedt
                                join GeographyGroup gg on gg.geographyGroupId = fedt.geographyGroupId
                                join GeographyName gn on gn.geographyGroupId = gg.geographyGroupId and gn.geographyNameId = fedt.geographyNameId
                                join GeographyMap gm on gm.geographyNameId = gn.geographyNameId
                                join industryMap iMatch on iMatch.industryNameId = fedt.industryNameId
                                join industryMap iInput on iInput.industryBaseId = iMatch.industryBaseId
                                     where gm.geographyBaseId = @domicileId and iInput.industryNameId = @industryId and fedt.coveragePolicyTypeId = @coveragePolicyTypeId and fedt.is953d = @is953D";

            var param = new { domicileId, industryId, coveragePolicyTypeId , is953D };

            return WithCache(sql, param, () =>
            {
                using (var conn = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    var data = conn.Query(sql, param).Select(dyn => new FedExciseExpense()
                    {
                     DomicileId = (int)dyn.domicileId,
                    CoveragePolicyTypeId = (int)dyn.coveragePolicyTypeId,
                    Is953D = (int)dyn.Is953d ,
                    Value = (decimal?)dyn.Value
                    }).ToList();

                    conn.Close();
                    return data;
                }
            });
        }



  private static T WithCache<T>(string query, object parameters, Func<T> execution)
        {
            var key = query;
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                key += "@" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters, Formatting.None);
            }
            return (T)QueryCache.GetOrAdd(key, _ => execution());
        }


Actual query 

    declare @domicileId int = 69,
            @industryId int = 52,
            @coveragePolicyTypeId int = 1,
            @is953D int = 1

select distinct gm.geographyBaseId as DomicileId, fedt.is953d as Is953D, fedt.coveragePolicyTypeId as CoveragePolicyTypeId, fedt.value as Value                                  from fedExciseTax fedt                                  join GeographyGroup gg on gg.geographyGroupId = fedt.geographyGroupId                                  join GeographyName gn on gn.geographyGroupId = gg.geographyGroupId and gn.geographyNameId = fedt.geographyNameId                                  join GeographyMap gm on gm.geographyNameId = gn.geographyNameId          join industryMap iMatch on iMatch.industryNameId = fedt.industryNameId                                  join industryMap iInput on iInput.industryBaseId = iMatch.industryBaseId                                       
where gm.geographyBaseId = @domicileId and iInput.industryNameId = @industryId and fedt.coveragePolicyTypeId = @coveragePolicyTypeId and fedt.is953d = @is953D
```

key value

Below is the value of key that is initialized in the WithCache method

```
select distinct gm.geographyBaseId as DomicileId, fedt.is953d as Is953D, fedt.coveragePolicyTypeId as CoveragePolicyTypeId, fedt.value as Value
                                from fedExciseTax fedt
                                join GeographyGroup gg on gg.geographyGroupId = fedt.geographyGroupId
                                join GeographyName gn on gn.geographyGroupId = gg.geographyGroupId and gn.geographyNameId = fedt.geographyNameId
                                join GeographyMap gm on gm.geographyNameId = gn.geographyNameId
                                join industryMap iMatch on iMatch.industryNameId = fedt.industryNameId
                                join industryMap iInput on iInput.industryBaseId = iMatch.industryBaseId
                                     where gm.geographyBaseId = @domicileId and iInput.industryNameId = @industryId and fedt.coveragePolicyTypeId = @coveragePolicyTypeId and fedt.is953d = @is953D@{"domicileId":69,"industryId":52,"coveragePolicyTypeId":0,"is953D":1}
```

Query that will take only query without parameters

```
private static List<T> RunQuery<T>(string query, object parameters = null)
        {
            return WithCache(query, parameters, () => RunNoCacheQuery<T>(query, parameters));
        }


        private static List<T> RunNoCacheQuery<T>(string query, object parameters = null)
        {
            using (var conn = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
            {
                conn.Open();
                var data = conn.Query<T>(query, parameters).ToList();
                conn.Close();
                return data;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is how you are trying to add the parameters to the query. Serliaizing an anonymous type to javascript and blindly concatenating to to the query seems very odd.  What is the final result of `key` in `WithCache`?

Comment: I have updated the post with the value of the key

Comment: OK That's what I would expect. That's not how parameters are added to SQL. You need to create `SQLParameter` objects, giving them the right name and value.  I don't know anything about `QueryCache.GetOrAdd` to know how that can be done. Is there another overload that can take parameter objects or can you only give it complete SQL?

Comment: updated the post with a method that will take only query and no parameters

Comment: RunQuery is eventually calling the WithCache method. Could you tell me how to do it

Comment: What i have noticed is that the filter upto here works  where gm.geographyBaseId = @@domicileId and iInput.industryNameId = @@industryId. Anything added after this it rejects however the complete filter works directly when run in sql server. Please note that i wrote @@ because , stackoverflow was treating it as notifying user in the comment.